# How to generate 100 different reference variable inside a for loop and switch-case?

Tags: java

I want to make 100 new instances based on `Position` enum types. In the switch case statement I have 5 cases, and based on the enum type I want to create corresponding `Employee` instances. My problem is, I have no idea how to create and assign new variable names, like: worker1, worker2, worker3 every time a new instance is created. Here is what I've come up so far:

```
final String randomVariableName() {
        int count = 1;
        String s = "worker" + count;
        count++;
        return s;
    }

final Position randomPosition(){
    return positions[random.nextInt(positions.length)];
}
public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        String randomName = "worker" + i;
        Position p = randomPosition();
        switch (p) {
            case PROJECT_LEADER:
                ProjectLeader randomVariableName() = new ProjectLeader(p, randomName, 5000);
            case DEVELOPER_LEADER:
                DeveloperLeader randomVariableName() = new DeveloperLeader(p, randomName, 1000);
        }
    }
```

But this way, I can't call the `randomVariableName()` method, because: `Variable 'randomVariableName' is already defined in the scope`

I'm not even sure, that this would be the good solution. I just need a way, to create 100 unique reference variable name, in the switch-case.

Comment: Simple Answer: You don't. Just create an array (or `ArrayList`) that you add new entries to

Comment: Why not just an array of `ProjectLeader`s? Is there any good reason why that would not be satisfactory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create new variable names at runtime in Java. What you can do is use an array, or a collection to store your instances.

```
Employee employees[] = new Employee employees[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        String randomName = "worker" + i;
        Position p = randomPosition();
        switch (p) {
            case PROJECT_LEADER:
                employees[i] = new ProjectLeader(p, randomName, 5000);
                break;
            case DEVELOPER_LEADER:
                employees[i] = new DeveloperLeader(p, randomName, 1000);
                break;
        }
    }
```

After the loop, you can access `employees[0]` through `employees[99]` to get at your 100 instances.

And even more appropriate than using a raw array would be to a collection, e.g. an `ArrayList<Employee>` which you add your instances to.

Also - remember to terminate your case statements with a break inside your switch()

Comment: I think the PO meant `new ProjectLeader(p, randomVariableName() , 5000);`

Comment: Probably not, the randomVariableName()  method does not work (it always returns "worker1")